# Rails 4: Order has_many in serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, serialization, has-many

I have a serializer with a `has_many` association and I want to order the dependent model.  For some reason I get an `undefined method key?'` error:

```
class API::ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    has_many :check_ins, -> { order(:week) }
end
```

**How else do I order the check_ins by week?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
class API::ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :check_ins do
    object.check_ins.order(:week)
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class API::ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :check_ins

  def check_ins
    object.check_ins.order(:week)
  end
end
```

Comment: Funny you recommended this, this is what I ended up doing I just thought there was a way to fix the initial syntax

Comment: Is there a way of sorting and using the check_ins serializer as well?